# Eclipse Debugging: Stay within boundries of current project

Tags: eclipse, debugging

When step-debugging in eclipse, is it possible to instruct the debugger to traverse only steps within my project's sources?

I am debugging a rails application and much of the calls are moving through rails' infrastructure (such as activerecord) which I am not interested in following. I would prefer the step-debugger to skip these files, instead hitting the next line within my own source files.

Comment: What about just to use "Step over"?

Comment: I have many complex statements where I'm calling a method relaying on ActiveRecord or similar framework code. I want to drill into my own code but not into external libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible in Java. I don't know if Ruby debugger in Eclipse has so mature as the Java one or not. Read [this](http://blog.firdau.si/2009/08/24/eclipse-tips-debugging-ignoring-certain-classes-from-being-stepped-into/).

Comment: Thanks. It does indeed seem that Step Filters aren't supported in RadRails.

Comment: Since the linked page seems to be down, here's a Internet Archive link for all future visitor's convenience: http://web.archive.org/web/20100728102110/http://blog.firdau.si/2009/08/24/eclipse-tips-debugging-ignoring-certain-classes-from-being-stepped-into/ (Unfortunately, the images do not seem to be archived.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can prevent Eclipse to "Step into" a code, even if it isn't *directly* part of your project.

The only filtering in place is provided with **[Mylyn](http://tasktop.com/mylyn/mylyn-2.0-part2.php)**, in order to help you to focus on "the current task" at hand, with a "context" you help define!

[image: Java Task Top]

Comment: Is the context enforced while step debugging?

Comment: @shmichael: that I am not sure about: step into is likely to go into a third-party code (if sources are there), potentially *expending* the scope.