# How can I skip runing into Android class code when debugging My own project?

Tags: android, eclipse

New to android, when I debugging in Eclipse I use to press F6 to step into my code, but by doing this, it always lead me into source code of Android which I don't have, than, you can see the page with a button let you to browse the location of the source code, how can I skip this, and let the debugger always stay within my own project?

Thanks.

Comment: That particular page dose show any message like 'source not found'?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the 'step over' command and not the 'step into' one? You should never end up in Android's own classes by stepping over. See this question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580715/eclipse-debug-step-into-step-over

Comment: He does have a point though. It would be a nice debugging feature to never step into a package that you do not have the source for in the current project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse Debugging: Stay within boundries of current project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179614/eclipse-debugging-stay-within-boundries-of-current-project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew it should be possible!

This is a duplicate of this: [Eclipse Debugging: Stay within boundries of current project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179614/eclipse-debugging-stay-within-boundries-of-current-project)

Comment: Really appreciate to have this quick answer.